# "At the back of your mind" or "in the back of your mind"

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is there any difference between these two expressions: *at the back of your mind* and *in the back of your mind*?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Both prepositions can be used. See a description [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-in-the-back-of-your-mind).